# Ansible & Vagrant development environment

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ansible

I have just discovered Ansible and it is great! I have written some cool playbooks to manage 0downtime docker deployments on my servers, but I waste quite a bit of time waiting things to happen due to the fact that I sometimes have to work with poor internet connection. So i thought, I might be able to run Ansible against boot2docker, but got no success and after doing a lil bit of research I realized it would be too hacky and it would never behave like my actual Ubuntu server. So here I am trying to make it work with Vagrant.

I want to achive something like **Laptop > Ansible > Vagrant Box**; don`t want to run the playbooks from the Vagrant Box!

#### VagrantFile

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
end
```

#### vagrant ssh-config

```
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile "/Users/cesco/Code/vagrant/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key"
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
  ForwardAgent yes
```

Thanks to some SO question I was able to do this:

```
$ vagrant ssh-config > vagrant-ssh
$ ssh -F vagrant-ssh default
$ vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$
```

But I keep getting `localhost | FAILED => SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey,password).`every time I try to run the Ansible ping ont the vagrant box.

#### Ansible inventory

```
[staging]
vagrant@localhost
```

#### Ansible config

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o   UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
           -o   StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
           -o   PasswordAuthentication=no \
           -o   IdentityFile=/Users/cesco/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key \
           -o   IdentitiesOnly=yes \
           -o   LogLevel=FATAL \
           -p 2222
```

How do I translate the ssh file to ansible configurantion?
It does not work on the command line also!

```
ssh -vvv vagrant@localhost -p 2222 -i /Users/cesco/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o LogLevel=FATAL -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understood well what what would you like to achieve - but is there a chance that Vagrant's [Anisble Provisoning plugin](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/ansible.html) may help? This way you define the playbooks in Vagrantfile and Vagrant takes care of connecting to the machine and running them.

Comment: I have read this but it actually run the playbooks from the vagrant box. A want to run playbooks against the box to mimic my real world server.

Comment: Like Laptop>Vagrant >Ansible > Anywhere. I want Laptop>Ansible>Vagrant

Comment: I will edit the question to make things clearer

Comment: Oh, OK. Did you check this guide? It explains the configuration for "manul" connection to the Vagrant machine: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_vagrant.html#running-ansible-manually

Comment: @Timur you are right! I got it now. I have had read that before but the fact that I need to run a playbook from the box anyway lead to think that this was not the right approach. I had to create [this] (https://gist.github.com/cescoferraro/156e1adb6f0f5ceadc41) "empty" playbook on the vagrant folder and run vagrant up && vagrant provision so it creates both a inventory and a key files inside .vagrant/

Comment: If you finally have a working configuration, I think it is best if you post it as an answer here and accept it, for those who might look into this question in the future ;)

Comment: @Timur I will thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use vagrant with and classic ssh connection, first add another private IP to your Vagrant file.

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.1.2"
```

Reload your instance

```
vagrant reload
```

Then you can connect by ssh using the private key.

```
ssh -vvv vagrant@192.168.1.2 -p 2222 -i /Users/cesco/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
```

That is the best way.

Comment: Vagrant map the guest port 22 to the port 2222 on the host, while trying to ssh using the private network ip you should not need to set the port because it the default 22. I am trying that right now, but the password does not match. I was able to get it right using `ssh vagrant@localhost -p 2222 -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i /Users/cesco/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key`

Comment: You are right about the conecction port . But if you  still use localhost never do a successful connection. Set a private IP and use that IP. If you have the private key don't need a password.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand. The vagrant ansible plugin **does not** run ansible from the vagrant, but instead SSHs into the vagrant from your local box. That's the way to go since it means with a few small changes you can target a remote host instead.

To get it working you need to add something like this to your Vagrantfile:

```
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
      ansible.playbook = "ansible/vagrant.yml"
      ansible.sudo = true
      ansible.ask_vault_pass = true       # comment out if you don't need
      ansible.verbose = 'vv'              # comment out if you don't want

      ansible.groups = {
        "tag_Role_myrole" => ["myrole"]
      }

      ansible.extra_vars = {
        role: "myrole"
      }
  end

  # Set the name of the VM. 
  config.vm.define "myrole" do |myrole|
    luigi.vm.hostname = "myrole"
  end
```

Create/update your `ansible.cfg` file with:

```
hostfile = ../.vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory
```

Create a `hosts` inventory file containing:

```
localhost=127.0.0.1  ansible_connection=local
```

Now `vagrant up` will bring up and provision the instance, or run `vagrant provision` to (re)provision a running vagrant.

To run a playbook directly against your vagrant use:

```
ansible-playbook -u vagrant --private-key=~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key yourplaybook.yml
```